# DOI links inside \texttt{} with \url{} line breaking

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter, doi, url

As in the title, is there any way to have `\doi{}`, apart from automatically inserting a link to an article, output into `\texttt{}` and break the line just like `\url{}` does? Unfortunately, I can't use anything that involves `.bib` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load `hyperref` you can use its `\nolinkurl` command to print a string as if it were a URL (fonts, linebreak and all) but without a link. You can then use `\href` to link the DOI to the proper target

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\doi{10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P}
\end{document}
```

[image: The image shows the DOI "10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P" typeset in the document surrounded by a box indicating it is a clickable link.]

Of course

```
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\nolinkurl{#1}}
```

would do the same without a link.

If you don't load `hyperref` and only use the `url` package, you can try

```
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\url{#1}}
```

instead.